# How can I efficiently resize sprites every frame?

Tags: libgdx, animation, sprites

I want to animate UI elements, like HP bars, by moving and resizing them. How can I efficiently resize sprites every frame?

I am using the LibGDX framework.

Comment: _A_ sprite? No. 23 thousand? Probably.

Comment: Would it be appropriate to edit this question to read as "How would I efficiently resize a sprite every frame?" so it can be answered cleanly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When creating your texture, fill in the 2nd parameter to tell LibGDX to generate a mipmap chain:

```
Texture tex = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("image.png"), true);
```

Then enable mipmapping in the texture filter:

```
tex.setFilter(TextureFilter.MipMapLinearLinear, TextureFilter.Linear);
```

This approach is hardware accelerated and there is no drawback to drawing the image at different sizes every frame.